# Once more: how to asynchronously fetch data in React Component before render?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, backend, server-side

Yes, I know it's a popular question and there are so many articles on the web. But I just give up with googling that up in my case.

I got server-side rendering of common (both, server and client) components that are supposed to use some kind of data provider (let's forget about redux for a moment). And there is a problem here...
I'll use typescript syntax.

So, let's look at a simplified Component example:

```
// This povider is supposed to be injected in component's props as a dependency
// Imagine this to load the 'name' value from DB
export interface IProvider {
    getName(id: number): Promise<string>
}

export class ShowName extends React.Component<{id: number, provider: IProvider}, {name: string}> {
    async componentWillMount(): Promise<void> {
        const provider = this.props.provider;

        this.setState({name: await provider.getName(this.props.id)});
    }

    render() {
        return <h1>{this.state.name}</h1>;
    }
}
```

It seems to be a common way to handle this.
It is transpiled and run without errors, but there is one problem I cannot solve. When the Component is rendered on server side, I got no 'name' value exposed, though all the operations are executed if I log them, component renders after the data is received asyncronously. But value is not rendered... 
Also I got a warning on backend console:

> Warning: setState(...): Can only update a mounting component. This usually means you called setState() outside componentWillMount() on the server. This is a no-op. Please check the code for the ShowName component.

So, what should I do about it?

**UPD** I guess, `componentWillMount` cannot work asynchronously in fact. I've just put some logging around it and found out that `render()` executes accurately after the `componentWillMount()`. And Promise (with `setState()`) is resolved after render. This sucks.

Comment: Have you tried using `componentDidMount`?

Comment: Sure. It doesn't work :) And not supposed to on backend according to https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentwillmount

Comment: For SSR, I think I would be tempted to do the data fetching outside of the React lifecycle, and pass it down to the React components as props (You can use the constructor to put it into state). You can then add a `componentDidMount` for the case where your component is client-side rendered - maybe with a check if the data is already present (Or abstract out into e.g. Redux). Have you thought about something like next.js?

Comment: Reading about it a bit, there seem to be issues with fetching data server side in lifecycle events. As mentioned by @MattHolland, `next.js` is definitely a life saver here. It's `getInitialProps` function can handle this situation easily.

Comment: Thanks for suggesting the next.js module, I'll look into it.

I don't think it is a good idea to fetch all the data in request handler (before react routing and rendering). It makes the handler know what components are used and what data is required. Bad for encapsulation, I think.